# Can I re-read my edited tmux.conf from within a tmux session?

Tags: mac, tmux

Trying to avoid having to close the tmux session just to change the key bindings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know where your config file is but the way <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>YOUR_BIND_KEY</kbd> and then <kbd>:</kbd> to bring up a command prompt, and typing:

```
:source-file ~/.tmux.conf
```

Source:

https://sanctum.geek.nz/arabesque/reloading-tmux-config/